# How to apply a function using map to each dict object of a list in python?

Tags: python

```
L = [{"id" : "1", "points": 100}, {"id" : "2", "points": 200}]
for obj in L:
    obj['id'] = int(obj['id'])
```

Is it possible to solve using map and lambda function?

Comment: What you have is very clear. Using map and a lambda would be much less readable. You *could* do something like: `map(lambda obj: dict(obj, **{'id':  int(obj['id'])}), L)`, but it's not an improvement.

Comment: If you want to apply `int` to *every* value in each dict, you could just use a list comprehension: `L = [{ k : int(v) for k, v in d.items() } for d in L]`

Comment: In this case, you are *mutating `L`*, so a for-loop is preferable anyway.

Comment: @Mark perhaps `map(lambda obj: dict(obj, int=int(obj['id'])), L)` is slightly more readable, but not by much

Comment: Yes, that’s nicer @juanpa.arrivillaga ... filing that away.